# How can I implement this shape into my code?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could implement [this shape](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EZRjYQ) into my website. Furthermore, when I copy and paste it into my website, the text position of the string "CLICK ON THE ARROW BELOW TO SCROLL DOWN" gets adjusted and I want it to stay above the arrow. [Here is my codepen](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EZLOdP)

I changed the hex colour to red so you can see what I mean.

Below is the HTML / CSS code for the rounded shape I want to implement within the middle of my website page. How could I also write text over this object?

```
<div id="shape">Rounded corners!</div>

#shape {
border-radius: 25px;
background: #111;
padding: 20px; 
width: 200px;
height: 150px;    
}
```

Comment: The text is already there over the object. You aren't seeing it because it is the same color as the background.

Answer (score 1):

The shape is already there. (?)

Concerning the text you write about: You have `margin-top:530px;` on your `p` tag, which makes it disappear behind another element. Erase or adjust that margin. And use a class on that element and its CSS, since otherwise all `p`  tags will get these settings.

P.S.: To center your `#shape` DIV, use these mergin settings on it (and no float):

```
margin:100px auto 0 auto;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaepGZ  (edited)

ADDITION:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxrpPY

--> This places the text above the arrow, giving it position absolute with horizontal centering and a fixed `bottom` setting:

```
.arrowtext {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 75px;
}
```

But you have to move that text container into your section, above the arrow element. See my second codepen for details.

Comment: Hi, I changed the text from a     <p>     tag to a class. In addition, I also removed the margin. However, where has my text gone? Can tell me what code I would need to adjust it to above the arrow please? [codepen site](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EZLOdP)

Comment: have you seen what I added to my answer, and have you looked at my codepen? Add the class to the p tag, don't put the p-tag in a div with a class. And use those margin settings on `#shape'